# [Amazon][JDBC](10220) Driver not capable

Tags: driver, pentaho, amazon-redshift

I am trying to update the table is redshift through Pentaho. Getting the below error message:

```
2016/11/24 18:15:37 - Dimension lookup/update.0 - Dimension Lookup setting preparedStatement to [SELECT cnsmr_id_KEY, Version, crm_cnsmr_id, trvs_core_cnsmr_id, cnsmr_first_name, cnsmr_last_name, cnsmr_email, contact_no, cnsmr_pswd, bus_id, primary_geo_id, cnsmr_loc_id, cnsmr_cc_handle, cnsmr_cc_desc, cnsmr_cc_expiry_date, bill_cycle_start_date, bill_cycle_end_date, registration_date, active_flag, deactivation_date, created_at, updated_at, created_by, updated_by, null, null FROM staging.trvs_consumer WHERE cnsmr_id = ?  AND ? >= null
2016/11/24 18:15:37 - Dimension lookup/update.0 -  AND ? < null
2016/11/24 18:15:37 - Dimension lookup/update.0 - ]
2016/11/24 18:15:38 - Dimension lookup/update.0 - Finished preparing dimension lookup statement.

2016/11/24 18:15:39 - Dimension lookup/update.0 - SQL w/ return keys=[INSERT INTO staging.trvs_consumer( Version, null, null, cnsmr_id, crm_cnsmr_id, trvs_core_cnsmr_id, cnsmr_first_name, cnsmr_last_name, cnsmr_email, contact_no, cnsmr_pswd, bus_id, primary_geo_id, cnsmr_loc_id, cnsmr_cc_handle, cnsmr_cc_desc, cnsmr_cc_expiry_date, bill_cycle_start_date, bill_cycle_end_date, registration_date, active_flag, deactivation_date, created_at, updated_at, created_by, updated_by) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )]

2016/11/24 18:15:39 - Dimension lookup/update.0 - ERROR (version 6.1.0.1-196, build 1 from 2016-04-07 12.08.49 by buildguy) : Because of an error this step can't continue: 
2016/11/24 18:15:39 - Dimension lookup/update.0 - Unable to prepare dimension insert :
2016/11/24 18:15:39 - Dimension lookup/update.0 - INSERT INTO staging.trvs_consumer( Version, null, null, cnsmr_id, crm_cnsmr_id, trvs_core_cnsmr_id, cnsmr_first_name, cnsmr_last_name, cnsmr_email, contact_no, cnsmr_pswd, bus_id, primary_geo_id, cnsmr_loc_id, cnsmr_cc_handle, cnsmr_cc_desc, cnsmr_cc_expiry_date, bill_cycle_start_date, bill_cycle_end_date, registration_date, active_flag, deactivation_date, created_at, updated_at, created_by, updated_by) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )

2016/11/24 18:15:39 - Dimension lookup/update.0 - [Amazon][JDBC](10220) Driver not capable.
```

From the pentaho forum, I came to know that its a kind of bug to generate NULL column (http://jira.pentaho.com/browse/PDI-2292)

For which I generated one empty row with surrogate key 0 and all other values NULL.

After this when I try and run the transformation, I get the below error.

`2016/11/24 21:00:32 - Dimension lookup/update.0 - INSERT INTO staging.trvs_consumer( null, created_at, updated_at, cnsmr_id, crm_cnsmr_id, trvs_core_cnsmr_id, cnsmr_first_name, cnsmr_last_name, cnsmr_email, contact_no, cnsmr_pswd, bus_id, primary_geo_id, cnsmr_loc_id, cnsmr_cc_handle, cnsmr_cc_desc, cnsmr_cc_expiry_date, bill_cycle_start_date, bill_cycle_end_date, registration_date, active_flag, deactivation_date, created_at, updated_at, created_by, updated_by) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )
2016/11/24 21:00:32 - Dimension lookup/update.0 - [Amazon][JDBC](10220) Driver not capable.`

How shall I proceed ?

Answer (score 1):

Pay attention to a string

```
2016/11/24 18:15:39 - Dimension lookup/update.0 - SQL w/ return keys=[INSERT INTO staging.trvs_consumer( Version, null, null, cnsmr_id, crm_cnsmr_id,
```

or in short

```
INSERT INTO staging.trvs_consumer( Version, null, null, cnsmr_id,
```

are you really want to insert into columns called null and null?

Comment: Hi Dzmitry, I have updated the error message in question. Please let me know, where I am faltering ?

Answer (score 0):

As I am using the Dimension\Lookup update, there is an option for capturing the SCD 2 type changes, where the data versioning is done in the table by the Pentaho transformation.

The error I was getting, was for the reason I was not passing values into Date From and Date until fields and hence it was being passed as Null. Null values in these fields obviously doesn't help the versioning cause and hence the error.

Please post here, if you get any further issues.